# bash mount works but not with cron

Tags: bash, macos, cron-task

I have a bash script that backups my files.
so I need to mount an external network drive first before I backup.

```
backupMount="/Users/[user]/Volumes/Router_HDD"

# Mount the backupdrive
mount -t smbfs //GUEST:@routerhdd/USB_Storage $backupMount
```

If I run this script straight from the terminal on my Mac, it works!
when I run this in a cronjob every 1st and 15th day of a month:

```
30 22 1,15 * * /Users/[user]/Documents/shFiles/rsbackup.sh live >/dev/null 2>&1
```

then he doesn't mount the share.
In this script I mail the report/log to myself and it says

> rsync: mkdir "/Users/[user]/Volumes/Router_HDD/Backups/Google Drive" failed: No such file or directory (2)

how can I fix this issue?

Regards,

Ralph

Comment: This might help: add a shebang and make your script executable.

Comment: That's the error from `rsync`, not from `mount`. You need to capture the output & errors from the entire script, not discard it with `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: Cyrus: ok I wil look in to that thanks,
GordonDavisson: rsync cant find the folder because it's not mounted,
when I run this bash file from the promt, then it works fine, including mounting

Comment: Who is the cron job running as? Is this a normal system based cron job in e.g. `/etc/cron.daily` or is this running as a user crontab or root crontab? Permission issue for cron creating/mounting in `/Users/[user]/Volumes`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm not so sure how I'm running cron. On my mac I open a terminal session and I type crontab -e I don't use sudo, so so can I assume that I run cron as the local user? If it's a permission case then it makes sence that I can't mout my drive

Comment: You are running a local user crontab. That will limit what you can do to your user. You will likely not be able to affect the home directory of any other user (unless you have write permission in their home directory). For system type cron jobs, either put the script in `/etc/cron.daily` (or hourly, etc..) but note the system cron generally runs as user `nobody` (I don't know what that means on mac), or as `root` create the `crontab -e` so the crontab runs as user root. These all slightly vary between distributions and I'm sure there are caveats on mac. But that's the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the `Privacy & Security` settings on your mac? You may need to grant full disk access to the cron executable: `\usr\sbin\cron`. That way, cron will have access to your home directory and any mounted network drives.
[image: Privacy & Security settings on mac os, with cron executable highlighted as having full disk access]